# How Can I use operator ternary in phalcon version 3.4 in volt?

Tags: phalcon, phalconeye

I would like to use the phalcon ternary operator provided by version 3.4, but I would like to use it with the one validation at the same time.

`{% set pageType = 'basicSetting' %} {{ pageType == 'basicSetting' ? 'class="active"' : '' }}`

The above example is from
[here](https://forum.phalcon.io/discussion/6581/ternary-operator-in-volt)

Answer (score 0):

After some research and analysis, I was able to find this,it is a little example

```
{% set result_that_you_want = (value==1) ? 'the result is 1' : 'the result is not the same the 1' %}
```